# Number of ways to divide a set of number so that sum is even for one set, but not both.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Alex and Jim want to share the numbers 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20. In how many different ways the ten numbers can be split between Alex and Jim so that each person gets at least one number and either Alex's numbers or Jim's numbers (but not both) sum to an even number?

I tried by enumerating all the possible cases, but it never ends. There are too many possibilites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

The condition that exactly one of the sums but not both, is even, is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). This is because total sum is odd, since there are five odd numbers present.

No matter how this set of ten integers is split into two subsets, one of the subsets will always sum to an even number while other will sum to an odd number.

So all you have to do is find the number of ways to split the given set into two non-empty subsets.

Comment: That will be 2 power 10, minus 2. Thanks. 
May I please know how did you deduce it quickly that no matter how this set of ten integers is split into two subsets, one of the subsets will always sum to an even number while other will sum to an odd number. Is it a general scenario that everytime a total sum is odd, the split will result in one even and another sum odd, irrespective of number of odd numbers? Is it essentially because of the logic that two sets adding up as an odd sum is always possible when either of them is necessary an odd sum and another even?

Comment: @LakshayKhanna Sum of two odd numbers, or two even numbers is even. Sum of two integers of opposite parity (E+O or O+E) is odd. Also, since total sum is fixed (parity), the sums of subsets do not have freedom to be of any parity.

Comment: If the total sum was even, then we would have proceeded it by forming cases where in sum in both sets is even, and then considering another case for odd sum in both. Further entailing possibilities of number of ways to select those set as an even total sum set, and both odd sum set. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is true.